# Did the druid in the DnD movie avoid the wizard at first, then get caught, due to die rolls?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, honor-among-thieves

Is that how it would have played out in a game? Like in the first room, while a fly, the druid is not detected, due to a successful die roll. But then in the next room, the druid is detected, due to a failed die roll. Would that be the best explanation why the druid wasn't detected at first? Or was there like a time limit before the druid would be caught, or another explanation?

Comment: The Red Wizard (Sofina) had *True Seeing* cast. As soon as she looked in the direction of Doric, she Spotted her automatically.

Comment: But how did Sofina detect her before that? When she said to be quiet?

Comment: What makes you think she didn't just see Doric then? She was just telling (from her perspective) insolent fools to stop distracting her with their idle chatter. Or she didn't have *True Seeing* up, but she had the Metamagic Adept feat and used it to cast a silent *True Seeing* as soon as she noticed the fly.

Comment: You can put your best explanation in an answer.

Comment: It would also need to explain why the druid was found in the 2nd room but not the first.

Comment: @Adamant - Sofina doesn't have True Seeing.

Comment: Sorry downvoters, but this is really quite interesting. It looks as if the makers of the film have *very carefully* checked the DND rules when they were writing this scene. Either that or they got enormously lucky

Comment: I also would think she would have looked at her in the first room, since the fly was in front of Forge's face.  Unless she was doing that look off to the side thing she does in conversations sometimes, I forget.

Comment: @Valorum - Of course, I checked the official stat blocks, but I think they were created after the script was written (or even after everything was filmed) in order to generally fit with the movie, not the other way around, meaning that they might not have gotten everything. The way that scene was written, with Sofina's certainty, definitely gave the impression that she had used some magical means of detecting that the fly was not a fly.

Comment: @Adamant - Her abilities and the underlying stats are certainly in keeping with earlier DnD depictions of dark wizards and such

Comment: @Valorum - Yes, but what I am saying is that someone cooked up an NPC monster statblock for each of these characters based on what they saw in the movies or the script, as well as filling in the blanks a bit. In reality, a wizard has a lot more spells than they show Sofina with, for instance. Although she certainly could not have had *true seeing* cast near the end.

Comment: True, she missed the kid

Comment: @Valorum - To see that it is obvious that the stat blocks cannot be a full description of the abilities of each character, note that Sofina clearly has some illusion or shapeshifting spell that allowed her to disguise herself as Edgin's daughter, but no illusion spell is mentioned in her statistics except *prestidigitation*, a cantrip which can at best produce an illusion of an object small enough to hold in one's hand.

Comment: @Adamant - Definitely worth asking as its own question

Comment: @Valorum - I don't think so. The answer is obvious: Sofina's stat block does not represent all her spells (obviously; she is a high-level wizard with substantial resources behind her and probably has dozens at least in her spellbook), which we know because we see her use one that is not there.

Comment: Has an official complaint been made to the stat block creators?

Comment: There's no need to complain to anyone. It's typical for D&D 5e stat blocks for NPCs or enemies to be very slimmed down. Sofina is at least level 17, and should know at least 38 spells (plus any that she copied into her spellbook), but not all of those are relevant for a given combat encounter.

Comment: In point of fact, she's probably level 20 with Boon of High Magic, since she cast both *meteor swarm* and *time stop* without a rest in between. Though I think the stat block shows her as level 19 based on the hit dice, but 20 would make more sense.

Comment: I guess an explanation with magic can be she was using more protective stuff when near the vault.

Comment: I heard the movie was not the most accurate with rest times, being a movie, like how the druid changed so much in a short period of time.

Comment: They might want to have her boss to be a higher lever wizard for the next movie, when the characters also level up more also. If they make another, it was funnier than most movies imho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DnD Beyond released [official stats blocks](https://www.dndbeyond.com/claim/bundle/dungeons-and-dragons-honor-among-thieves) for each of the film's main characters, including Sofina. Note that her Perception is a [*'passive'*](https://dicedungeons.com/blogs/inside/passive-perception) skill, which means that there isn't a need to continually roll for checks.

Assuming the makers of the film were following the rules, the DM would have performed a ***(passive) Perception check*** to see whether she could sense the fly. Being distracted with other tasks lowered her score sufficiently that the fly went undetected in the first room, but once she moved to the other room *and the distractions were gone*, her perception score would have risen, allowing her to see the disguised threat.

> [image: Sofina's stat block, with a passive Perception of 12]

> Passive Perception. When you hide, there's a chance someone will
> notice you even if they aren't searching. To determine whether such a
> creature notices you, the DM compares your Dexterity (Stealth) check
> with that creature's passive Wisdom (Perception) score, which equals
> 10 + the creature's Wisdom modifier, as well as any other bonuses or
> penalties. If the creature has advantage, add 5. For disadvantage,
> subtract 5. For example, if a 1st-level character (with a proficiency
> bonus of +2) has a Wisdom of 15 (a +2 modifier) and proficiency in
> Perception, he or she has a passive Wisdom (Perception) of 14.
>
> <sub><sup>[DND Beyond: Using Ability Scores](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/using-ability-scores)</sup></sub>
>
> Characters who turn their attention to other tasks as the group travels are not focused on watching for danger. These characters don’t contribute their passive Wisdom (Perception) scores to the group’s chance of noticing hidden threats.
>
> <sub><sup>[DND Beyond: Basic Rules - Adventuring](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/adventuring)</sup></sub>

Doric has a combined Dexterity score of 19. Sofina has a Perception check score of 22 (12+10). When Doric has 'Advantage' she gains 5 stealth points and would remain undetected (24 versus 22). When she loses that advantage, she would be detected (19 versus 22).

---

To some extent this ties in with the [official novelisation](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Honor_Among_Thieves:_The_Junior_Novelization). Doric seems to have lost her advantage because she came *too close* to Sofina.

> “Truth is,” Forge explained, “the Games bring the city together like
> nothing else. It’s not the role of government to deny the people what
> they crave.” He paused. “Or to deny you stinking-rich gentlemen the
> right to profit off them.”
>
> Piradost and Caldwell laughed. **The fly buzzed closer—close enough to
> see Sofina’s markings under her hood. The Red Wizard grew alert,
> sensing an intruder.**
>
> “Now, who wants refreshments?” Forge asked, rubbing his hands
> together.
>
> “Silence!” Sofina hissed. “A Wild Shape is among us!”
>
> The men looked around, puzzled. They saw nothing out of the ordinary.
> But Sofina spotted the fly and let out a bloodcurdling shriek.
> Immediately, the fly slipped into a crack in the wall.

Comment: Sofina spotted Doric ***because she was written that way.***

Comment: @Lexible - Hush now. Your logic and common-sense have no place here in this magical realm of whimsy.

Comment: @Lexible If any question about why a character does something in a movie can be answered with "Because the character was written that way," then we might as well pack it up and go home.

Comment: This makes sense since she was talking in the first room, but in the second room, probably trying to ignore their conversation,  which she probably found annoying, judging by later comments about the con man.

Comment: I'm not so clear she got closer in the movie in the 2nd room though, but yeah maybe there were movements back and forth not seen, or clear to see.

Comment: Or is this when they discovered she was a red wizard in the movie? I forget. Though maybe in the movie moving close wasn't needed, in any case.

Comment: And is perception all tht is needed to detect a druid in another form? It's not more for detecting hidden thieves?

Comment: @user14094230 - Perception would detect a druid in animal form.

Comment: Ok kewl, thanks

Comment: @Kyralessa No dice were rolled to order the plot points of the film.